# Different chapter headings using the geometry package

Tags: chapters

I would like to see the code to get different chapter headings.

In the following code, I have "Chapter 1" and its title typeset on page 1 just the way that I want it, and I have its title typeset in the Table of Contents just the way that I want it.

On page 2, I have "Chapter 2" and its title typeset, but I do not want "Chapter 2" to be typeset. I still want its title to be in the Table of Contents, though.

On page 3, I have "Chapter 3" and its title typeset, but I do not want "Chapter 3" to be typeset, and I want the title to be typeset in \Huge font centered at the top of the page. I also want its title to be in the Table of Contents.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{book}

%Some packages
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{sectsty} % not with titlesec
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  bindingoffset=0.0in,
  left=1.5in,
  right=1in,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
  footskip=.25in,
  %showframe,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},urlcolor={black}}


\urlstyle{same}
\allowdisplaybreaks


%This package allows Chapter titles to be single spaced.
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\setstretch{0.2}\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filright}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\setstretch{0.2}\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filright}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

%Allows the first line in  paragraph to be indented.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@afterheading}{}% or \let\@afterheading=\relax
\makeatother

%Makes page numbers appear
\pagestyle{plain}


\begin{document}



%Makes the page numbers roman numerals, and doesn't count these pages in the table of contents.
\frontmatter

\newgeometry{margin=0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-\topskip}
\vspace*{\fill}
\centerline{\Huge\bfseries The Rules of Arithmetic}
\vbox to 0pt{
  \vspace{1in}
  \centering
  \bfseries\Large Positive, Rational Numbers
  \vss
}
\vspace*{\fill}
\restoregeometry

\mainmatter



\chapter{Definition of Fractions}



In this first chapter, we will blah, blah-blah.



\chapter{Arithmetic with Fractions}

In this second chapter, we will blah, blah-blah.


\chapter{Converting Fractions to Decimals}

In this third chapter, we will blah, blah-blah.

\end{document}
```

Comment: geometry package is just about page dimensions and unrelated to chapter headings

Comment: `\renewcommand{\@afterheading}{}% or \let\@afterheading=\relax`  don't do that!!!! It will break latex.

Comment: @David Carlisle How would you allow the first line in the first paragraph of every chapter to be indented?

Comment: the core latex release includes an `indentfirst` package (which as it happens I wrote) which has fewer tokens than `\renewcommand{\@afterheading}{}` and does not break latex's section handling

Comment: If you don't typeset "Chapter 2", is it still chapter 2?  Are there sections in the chapter?  Are you wanting to end up with "Chapter 1, Arithmetic with Fractions, Converting Fractions to Decimals, Chapter 4", or with "Chapter 1, Arithmetic with Fractions, Converting Fractions to Decimals, Chapter 2"?

Comment: but you don't need indentfirst here as you are declaring the chapter heading, so simply specify indentation by changing the sign of the argument